# Vimeo video live upload

Tags: vimeo, live-streaming, chunks

I need to upload webcam recording live video on the Vimeo server.
One way I am trying is get the video blobs periodically and upload it to the server but I couldn't able to find the API details in the Vimeo documentation.

Comment: Can you provide technical details about what exactly you have attempted? What you're trying, what you're observing, etc. I recommend editing your query to include that information.

Comment: basically I am using recordRTC javascript API to record the video at the same time I need to upload it to the server to avoid the time required to upload the whole video file onto the Vimeo server.

Comment: The Vimeo API only allows uploading of completed video files; uploading of in-progress streaming video is not yet possible with the public API.

Comment: @TommyPenner I have also same issue, want to upload recording video as its occurring but couldn't got any detail. What about "TUS PROTOCOL"? can we use this protocol for live streaming upload same like as  completed resumable video upload to vimeo? Thanks

Comment: Only complete video files can be uploaded to Vimeo.

Comment: Hello @TommyPenner do you know if the API was updated to work with live streaming?

Comment: @Limitky Yes, but only Vimeo Enterprise customers have access to the Live API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/live

Comment: Thanks @TommyPenner, i already upgrade to Vimeo Enterprise. I integrated the API, but they say that is necesary to send a message to activate the functionality of create events for live stream, didn´t have an answer yet, do you know what i could do?

Comment: @Limitky if you have Vimeo Enterprise, you have an account manager who can work with you directly, I'd recommend talking to them.